# How to manually calculate the variance of the least squares estimator in R

Tags: regression, r

As stated in the title, how do you manually calculate the variance of the least squares estimator in R?

I know that the least estimates have the following formula:

$$\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1} X^T Y, $$

and the variance of the least squares estimator is given by

$$Var(\hat{\beta}) = σ^2(X^TX)^{−1}$$

My question clearly stated how to do that "manually," so I can understand that concept comprehensively. An R example would only serve to help me understand this concept.  I can easily find in R ($^T$), but what about $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's build the entire example (You can use the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) page for reference on all formula below):

First, generate the model parameters (p=4 in this case)

```
p <- 4
beta <- rnorm(p)
```

Next let's simulate some observations from a linear model:

```
n <- 100
X <- cbind(1,t(replicate(n, rnorm(p-1))))
epsilon <- rnorm(n)
y <- X%*%beta + epsilon
```

Let's also obtain our estimates for $\beta_i$:

```
beta_hat <- solve((t(X)%*%X))%*%t(X)%*%y
```

Now we can calculate model predictions:

```
pred <- X%*%beta_hat
```

And finally calculate $\hat{\sigma}^2$:

```
sigma_2 <- sum((y-pred)^2)/(n-p)
```

Just for sports let's also calculate $Var(\hat{\beta})$:

```
beta_hat_covariance <- solve(t(X)%*%X)*sigma_2
beta_hat_var <- diag(beta_hat_covariance)
```

To make sure all our calculations are correct we can believe the `lm` function is the source of truth and do:

```
my_lm_summary <- summary(lm(y ~ X-1))

# our calculation:
sigma_2
# is the same as:
my_lm_summary$sigma^2
# our calculation:
beta_hat_var
# is the same as:
my_lm_summary$coefficients[,2]^2
```